# Why won't main method print anything?

Tags: java, netbeans, program-entry-point

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with my code. I have to build a GUI and there are no errors. The program builds successfully, but no GUI pops up. So in the main method, I commented out the GUI programming and added a simple `System.out.println("hello");` but it does the same thing, i.e., it builds successfully, but does not print anything. Can someone please tell me what's wrong? Thanks!

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package gui;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    GridLayout g = new GridLayout(5, 2);
    private JLabel baseIn = new JLabel("Base Input");
    private JLabel heightIn = new JLabel("Height Input");
    private JTextField base = new JTextField();
    private JTextField height = new JTextField();
    private JTextField area = new JTextField();
    private JButton calc = new JButton("Calculate Area");

    public GUI() {
        super("Triangle Area Calculator");
        setSize(500, 300);
        setLayout(g);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(baseIn);
        add(heightIn);
        add(base);
        add(height);
        add(area);
        add(calc);
        area.setEditable(false);
        calc.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            double bInput = Integer.valueOf(base.getText());
            double hInput = Integer.valueOf(height.getText());
            double aOutput = 0.5*bInput*hInput;
            area.setText("Area of your triangle is: " + aOutput);
        } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
            System.out.println(n.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        GUI one = new GUI();

        frame.getContentPane().add(one);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);*/

        System.out.println("hello world");

    }

}
```

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: @Mureinik I'm using netbeans, the green play button (Run project, (F6))

Comment: You have to also tell NetBeans what's the main class of your project.  In your case, your main class appears to be `gui.GUI`.  Have you done that?

Comment: @MikeNakis I just checked in the project properties, and the main class is gui.GUI already, so I'm not sure why it's doing this.

Comment: Also, where do you expect the output to show up? Verify that you have not inadvertently hidden the NetBeans terminal.

Comment: @JanusVarmarken I've commented out what should originally show, and that's a new gui that calculates the area of a triangle based on user input. Since that showed nothing but a successful build in the run area, I commented it out and asked a system print in the run area instead.

I'm still new to Netbeans, though. What is hiding the terminal?

Comment: @user10372322 I'm not familiar with NetBeans (I prefer IntelliJ IDEA myself), but most IDEs will print to an embedded terminal window when the program is run from within the IDE. Also, most IDEs allows the user to show/hide different sections of them, so just make sure that the terminal is indeed shown (e.g., in IntelliJ one navigates to View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal). However, it's probably easier to just compile the program from the command line (using whatever terminal is available on your system) and then execute the program from to see if  it does or doesn't print to std.out

Comment: @user10372322 Based on your available code, you should have gotten at least one of two runtime errors - the first stating that you can't add a window based class to another container and, if you could solve that, attempting to cast `GUI` to `ActionListener` is an invalid cast.  Both of these will crash your app

Answer (score 3):

First, going back to the basic code...

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {
    //...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        GUI one = new GUI();

        frame.getContentPane().add(one);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Will fail, because you can't add a window based component to a window.  As a general rule of thumb, you should avoid overriding `JFrame` (and other top level containers) directly and favour something less complex, like `JPanel`

```
public class GUI extends JPanel {
    //...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new GUI());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Next...

```
calc.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
```

The fact that you need to perform a cast in order to get the code to work is a clear sign that something else is wrong and this is likely to cause a runtime error and crash your program.  Perhaps you should start by having a read of [How to write a Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) to get a better understanding of how the API works

This is further supported by making use of the `@Override` annotation, which should be used when ever you "think" you're implementing or overriding existing functionality...

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //...
}
```

This would then fail to compile, as you're not implementing any existing functionality.  This functionality is described by the `ActionListener` interface which you are not implementing.

While you could implement this interface directly, I prefer to avoid doing so, as it exposes functionality that other classes shouldn't have access to and you run the risk of building a "god" method, which is never a good idea.

Instead, I prefer to make use of Java's [Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), which provides a much better means for isolating functionality to single use case, for example...

```
calc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            double bInput = Integer.valueOf(base.getText());
            double hInput = Integer.valueOf(height.getText());
            double aOutput = 0.5 * bInput * hInput;
            area.setText("Area of your triangle is: " + aOutput);
        } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
            System.out.println(n.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

## Runnable Example

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUI extends JPanel {

    GridLayout g = new GridLayout(5, 2);
    private JLabel baseIn = new JLabel("Base Input");
    private JLabel heightIn = new JLabel("Height Input");
    private JTextField base = new JTextField();
    private JTextField height = new JTextField();
    private JTextField area = new JTextField();
    private JButton calc = new JButton("Calculate Area");

    public GUI() {
        setLayout(g);
        add(baseIn);
        add(heightIn);
        add(base);
        add(height);
        add(area);
        add(calc);
        area.setEditable(false);
        calc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    double bInput = Integer.valueOf(base.getText());
                    double hInput = Integer.valueOf(height.getText());
                    double aOutput = 0.5 * bInput * hInput;
                    area.setText("Area of your triangle is: " + aOutput);
                } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
                    System.out.println(n.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new GUI());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

## Netbeans properties...

Now, if all that still fails to net you a result, you need to make sure that your `GUI` class is configured as the "Main class".

Start by right clicking the Netbeans project node and select "Properties" (it's at the bottom).

From the "Projects Properties", select "Run" from the "Build" options down the left side.

Make sure that your `GUI` class is marked as the "Main Class", use "Browse" to find it if it's not

[image: Project Properties]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
calc.addActionListener(new OptionButtonHandler());
```

I added one optionButtonHandler class which implements ActionListener. I checked on my IDE and I was able to get the area of the triangle.

```
private class OptionButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        double bInput = Integer.valueOf(base.getText());
        double hInput = Integer.valueOf(height.getText());
        double aOutput = 0.5 * bInput * hInput;
        area.setText("Area of your triangle is: " + aOutput);
    } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
        System.out.println(n.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

In your case, GUI is not an ActionListener, so that will fail.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you right click on the file with the main method in Netbeans, you should see the run option there, select it. This would allow you set your main method. After this, subsequent clicks on the Green play Button should work.
2. You do not need to cast your Frame class to an ActionListener. Instead, make it implement the ActionListener interface and your code for the button action should work. But in future, its better to add logic to detect what component triggered the action.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know, but how can you write this :

```
calc.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
```

Your object (this) is a JFrame, you should add 'implements ActionListener' first, or create a separate implementation ...

Next error, you do :

```
GUI one = new GUI();
frame.getContentPane().add(one);
```

GUI extends JFrame, its a JFrame, you can't add a JFrame in another one !

I tested with add of 'implements ActionListener' and it runs, but some errors remains ;)
Copy/paste needs wisdom, hum ^^

**EDIT**

this code is not perfect (and very ugly) but it works for your example :

```
package com.mead.helmet.core;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class GUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

public static void main(final String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Triangle Area Calculator");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GUI one = new GUI();

    frame.getContentPane().add(one);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println("hello world");

}

GridLayout g = new GridLayout(5, 2);
private final JLabel baseIn = new JLabel("Base Input");
private final JLabel heightIn = new JLabel("Height Input");
private final JTextField base = new JTextField();
private final JTextField height = new JTextField();
private final JTextField area = new JTextField();

private final JButton calc = new JButton("Calculate Area");

public GUI() {
    super();
    setSize(500, 300);
    setLayout(g);
    add(baseIn);
    add(heightIn);
    add(base);
    add(height);
    add(area);
    add(calc);
    area.setEditable(false);
    calc.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);

    setVisible(true);
}

/**
 *
 * @param event
 */

@Override
public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        double bInput = Integer.valueOf(base.getText());
        double hInput = Integer.valueOf(height.getText());
        double aOutput = 0.5 * bInput * hInput;
        area.setText("Area of your triangle is: " + aOutput);
    } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
        System.out.println(n.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I tried adding the action listen to calc like calc.addActionListener(this); originally, but it wouldn't let me post. If I use implements ActionListener, it gives me errors. I'm doing this for a class and it doesn't do the same for my classmates though, so I'm wondering what's the problem. The same goes for the other errors. Do you have any solutions?